# ControlValueAccessor and FormControl Value are out of sync

Tags: angular, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I have implemented a `mask` on my input to allow only a special format. The mask is working correctly, but when the user enters letters, for example, it is attached to the `formControl value`, even when the field does not show it.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask-qjaj7f?file=app%2Fphone-mask.directive.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accessor.writeValue is a way to update the value inside of the input, but not in the logical model. The shortest fix is

```
if(newVal != event) this.ngControl.control.setValue(newVal);
```

this will update the value inside of the control

Comment: This didn't change anything

Comment: is it possible for you to upgrade Angular version? with this change and an update it should work

Comment: Ok it worked with Angular 12, thanks!